# jQuery.when().then() not working with select change event

Tags: jquery

I have some code in a page that load the list of cities when i change country select box.

I am trying to set up the default in the page using the flowing code but the jquery after the .then is not working. any ideas?

The country works perfect but the city is not loading.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('#jr_country').val('united-kingdom');
       jQuery.when( jQuery('#jr_country').change() ).then( jQuery('#jr_city').val('london') );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.when()` accepts jquery `$.Deferred` object, while `.change()` returns jquery object instance.

If you want to use promises in your code - rewrite it to something like:

```
var d = jQuery.Deferred().then(...);
jQuery('#jr_country').change(d.resolve);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/QuU3f/

Comment: Hi thanks a lot i am not sure i am getting how to implement the deferred the jQuery('#jr_country').change(); it is generating the city select so i have to run first the change and after the jQuery('#jr_city').val('london')

Comment: @open-ecommerce.org: here is a good reading about it: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: Thanks a lot i think i have a problem i the logic of the page. I will study the link you sent me thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**You can evaluate on index**

```
    $("#select_id").change(function () {
    if ($("#select_id")[0].selectedIndex == 1){
      // Do something
    }
    });
```

and you can evaluate on value via

```
    $("#select_id").val();
```